# Haskell flag pattern writing function?

Tags: haskell

I really need help in writing this function in Haskell, I don't even know where to start. Here are the specs:

Define a function flagpattern that takes a positive Int value greater than or equal to five and returns a String that can be displayed as the following `flag' pattern of dimension n, e.g.

```
Main> putStr (flagpattern 7)

#######  
##   ##  
# # # #  
#  #  #  
# # # #  
##   ##  
#######
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this supposed to look like an ASCii-art number 7?  Could you specify the problem in words and not in a single example?

Comment: @Thomas: It looks like a cross in a box of size 7x7 to me.
You can use recursion to create the cross.

Comment: How does it then look for an even n? Also, I don't see how this is haskell-specific, its mostly problem solving in general, no?

Comment: Its hard o help you if you don't even know where to start. StackOverflow works better on m ore specific questions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a "X" enclosed in 4 lines, you need to write a function that given a coordinate (x,y) returns what character should be at that position:

```
coordinate n x y = if i == 0 then 'X' else ' '
```

(This version outputs only the leftmost X'es, modify it, remember indices start with 0)

Now you want them nicely arranged in a matrix, use a [list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out), described in the linked text.

Answer (score 1):

You should start from your problem definition:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStr . flagPattern $ 7
```

Then, you should ask yourself about how much dots flag has:

```
flagPattern :: Int -> String
flagPattern = magic $ [1..numberOfDots]
```

Then, (hard) part of `magic` function should decide for each dot whether it is   or `#`:

```
partOfMagic ...
  | ...       = "#" -- or maybe even "#\n" in some cases?
  | otherwise = " "
```

Then, you can concatenate parts into one string and get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the type signature.

```
flagpattern :: Int -> String
```

Now break the problem into subproblems. For example, suppose I told you to produce row 2 of a size 7 flag pattern. You would write:

```
XX   XX
```

Or row 3 of a size 7 flag pattern would be

```
X X X X
```

So suppose we had a function that could produce a given row. Then we'd have

```
flagpattern :: Int -> String
flagpattern size = unlines (??? flagrow ???)

flagrow :: Int -> Int -> String
flagrow row size = ???
```

`unlines` takes a list of Strings and turns it into a single String with newlines between each element of the list. See if you can define `flagrow`, and get it working correctly for any given row and size. Then see if you can use `flagrow` to define `flagpattern`.